# Change Disk Type In Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, disk

How can I change the disk type in an Azure storage account disk from Premium to Standard (SSD to HDD)?

For example, in my windows server VM the disk is configured to be a Premium.  I no longer need it to be an SSD for the type of usage so I would like to change it to Standard.  But it is greyed out.  The VM is not currently running.

[image: azure vm disk type settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disk type is configured at the time of creating the Azure Storage Account. The disk type is used to determine the physical hardware that hosts your Azure Storage Account within the Azure data center.

Currently, you are NOT able to change the disk type of a storage account after creation, and it's tied to that particular disk type. Unfortunately, if you need to change disk types, then you will need to copy your VM .vhd disk images to a new storage account that uses HDD disk type, then create the Azure VM to use the .vhd disk image from the new storage account.